# magento working of paypal express checkout

Tags: magento

i was wondering how paypal Ecc works in magento.
When i see the source of the checkout page in magento cart,i do not see a form to send the request to the paypal.
COuld some explain me how it works in magento?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button on cart page links to the url "STORE.DOMAIN/paypal/express/start/" which is ultimately handled by `startAction()` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php`. This simply builds a parametrised URL to paypal's servers and redirects the user there.

Comment: Thank you for this- I haven't been able to display my paypal checkout button, but now I can add a buttpon with this URL and it works just fine!